# Finding repeating values in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with 4 integers and I need to find if there any repeating values and what are those repeating values. I have tried to use nested loops but it counts each integer in array twice:

```java
for (int f = 0; f < bonusGame.length; ++f) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bonusGame.length; ++j) {
        if (f == j & f == 10) {
            System.out.println("You won 10 Euro");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does not access the values in `bonusGame` at all. So how is it suppose to find duplicate values?

Comment: @Turing85 yeah, I know that is why I'm trying to ask for help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
for (int f = 0; f < bonusGame.length - 1; ++f) {
    for (int j = f + 1; j < bonusGame.length; ++j) {
        if (bonusGame[f] == bonusGame[j]) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate " + bonusGame[f]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell why in the first for loop there is bonusGame.length - 1? I can not understand why there is -1

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i= array.lenght;i >0;i--){
      if (array[i]==array[i-1]){
         system.out.print("you won ")
}
 }
```

// i think it will work

Comment: Even ignoring the syntax errors, [it won't work](https://ideone.com/QRUvmm).

Comment: why ?? could you give me more calrifation?

Comment: sorry for the syntax it has been ayear since i write java

Comment: i think it is the same

Comment: Look at the link in my comment. It provides a sample array with duplicates, which are not found. It is not sufficient to only compare direct neighbors.

Comment: because instead of minsing array lenght -1 i removed the equal

Comment: ohh right right sorry

Comment: thanks alot for your calrification

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `HashSet`. This way you can create a O(n) algorithm, but you have to use Integer instead of int, which can be a problem in some case :

```java
for (int num : bonusGame) {
     if (!hashSet.add(num) ) { // unauto-boxing
        // num is duplicate
     }
```

Or, you can call `Arrays.sort(bonusGame)` and compare the elements with only one loop :

```java
Arrays.sort(bonusGame);
for(int i=0 ; i<bonusGame.length - 1; i++) {
    if(bonusGame[i] == bonusGame[i+1]) {
         // bonusGame[i] is duplicate
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a `Set` does not guarantee linar time complexity. Using a `HashSet` will most likely guarntee linear time complexity.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: @FlorianS.  is there any way to do this only with nested loops?

Comment: @RuslanPylypiuk Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- To answer your question: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do it with nested loops though?  You can do this in linear time, not sure why you'd opt for O(n^2) time.